# Xamarin IOS InAppBiling plugin how to get receipt-data

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, in-app-purchase

I use Plugin.InAppBiling for In-App Purchase ios. I want to know Purchase receipt data.

here is my code.

```
private async Task<bool> MakePurchase(string productId)
        {
            var billing = CrossInAppBilling.Current;
            try
            {
                var connected = await billing.ConnectAsync();

                if (!connected)
                {   
                    return false;
                }

                var verify = DependencyService.Get<IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase>();
                var purchase = await CrossInAppBilling.Current.PurchaseAsync(productId, ItemType.InAppPurchase, verify);
                
                if (purchase == null)
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else if (purchase.State == PurchaseState.Purchased)
                {
                 
                    if (Device.RuntimePlatform == Device.iOS)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("CHECK");
                        if(verify == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("null");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"{verify}");
                        }
                        
                    }
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }
            finally
            {
                await billing.DisconnectAsync();
            }
        }
```

The payment process goes well. but verify is just return null.

I understood verify as receipt-data. It's right?

How do I get a base64 encoded string receipt-data?

Comment: What is `IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase`? Is this a interface you've made yourself?

Comment: public interface IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase
    {
        Task<bool> VerifyPurchase(string signedData, string signature, string productId = null, string transactionId = null);
    }

Comment: This is the interface implemented by the plugin

Comment: [link]https://jamesmontemagno.github.io/InAppBillingPlugin/SecuringPurchases.html

Comment: And what you get as result in `verify` is what? null?

Comment: yes, I get the result to null. I have 3 products and the purchase completes fine. But my 3 items are all return null.

Comment: Yes, but you didn't implement this interface yourself and register it in the IoC container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation you also link to clearly states that *you* need to implement `IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase` yourself. There is no implementation of this in the plugin.

So you need to create your own class and register it in the IoC container:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(MyIAPVerification))]
public class MyIAPVerification : IInAppBillingVerifyPurchase
{
    // implementation here
}
```

Only then will your `verify` instance not be null.

Comment: oh, thank. It's my first time trying, I couldn't read the documentation very well. i'll try it.